# Dynamic link to other workbook in Excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, hyperlink

In cell A1 I have a path to an external Excel-file:

```
C:\Users\John\Stuff\MySourceFile.xlsm
```

In cell A2 I have a hardcoded link pointing to a specific cell in that external file to show the value.

```
='C:\Users\John\Stuff\[MySourceFile.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1
```

**Question:** How can I edit the cell A2 to make the link dynamic so that if I change the A1 value, the A2 would automatically relink to the new file? (Note: Looking for a no-VBA solution)

Comment: `Looking for a no-VBA solution` - would work only for *opened workbooks* use INDIRECT function.

Comment: Target files are closed here always

Comment: Unfortunatelly, there is no way without VBA